# changing size of div on hover in multiple rows messing up design (moving to side)

Tags: html, css

hi im trying to create a design with css that will enlarge the image in a div of a "button" so to speak and lower all elements down. if i have a single row there is no problem the row moves down as per the size of the button on image being enlarged, but multiple rows will mess up the design so that the the surrounding elements move to right.

relevant code:

```css
#dialer{
    width:1040px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}


#dialer_wrap{
    width:1040px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}

.dialer1 p{
    font-size:1em;font-weight: bolder;

}

.dialer1 a {
    width:60%;
    color:#fff;
}

.dialer1 img:hover {
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:4em;
}

.dialer1 img{
    width:60%;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dialer1
{
    width:10%;
    color:#fff ;
    text-align:center;
    background:#1F9BCB ;
    margin:0.25em;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialer_wrap">

    <img class="top" src="images/dialksa.png">        

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">

            <p>
                Android
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img class="top" src="images/dialaplus.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iteliTelmd/id445338527?mt=8">

            <p>
                Apple
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialap.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29163891/?lang=en&countrycode=BD ">
            <p>
                Blackberry
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialbb.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/itelmobiledialer/de0e1e5b-aaad-40b5-bc34-ea60159b7851 ">
            <p>
                Windows
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialw.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">
            <p>
                Nokia
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialn.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>
            PC
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialp.png">        
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">
            OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>
            Aero Voice
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialav.png">        
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">
            OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>

    <img class="top" src="images/dialksa.png">        

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">

            <p>
                Android
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img class="top" src="images/dialaplus.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iteliTelmd/id445338527?mt=8">

            <p>
                Apple
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialap.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29163891/?lang=en&countrycode=BD ">
            <p>
                Blackberry
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialbb.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/itelmobiledialer/de0e1e5b-aaad-40b5-bc34-ea60159b7851 ">
            <p>
                Windows
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialw.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <a a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">
            <p>
                Nokia
                <br>Dialer</p>
            <img src="images/dialn.png">        
            <p class="button">Download</p>
            <p class="button">
                OP CODE
                <br>22960</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>
            PC
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialp.png">        
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">
            OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>
            Aero Voice
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialav.png">        
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">
            OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/28s3vnus/1/

images are not available but problem is shown even as is.

basically i want to be able to hover over any of the buttons and move all elements down as per the change in size of div. currently first row is making second row move to side while bottom row is correct.

thanks

Comment: please do not advise regarding fixed positions that will mess with the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify `.dialer1 img:hover` as follows, so it doesn't really much shift your dialers:

```
.dialer1 img:hover {
  width:100%;
  margin-top:-10%;
  margin-bottom:-10%;
}
```

But as you can see the images will overlap the top text then. So then add `padding-top:4px;` to `.dialer1 img` (you can increase this padding or also add `padding-bottom` if you wish).

End result:

```css
#dialer{
 width:1040px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;

}


#dialer_wrap{
 width:1040px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;

}

.dialer1 p{
 font-size:1em;font-weight: bolder;
}

.dialer1 a {
 width:60%;
 color:#fff;
}

.dialer1 img:hover {
  width:100%;
  margin-top:-10%;
  margin-bottom:-10%;
}

.dialer1 img{
    padding-top:4px;
 width:60%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dialer1
{
 width:10%;
 color:#fff ;
 text-align:center;
 background:#1F9BCB ;
 margin:0.25em;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialer_wrap">
    <img class="top" src="images/dialksa.png">
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">

<p>Android<br>Dialer</p>
<img class="top" src="images/dialaplus.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iteliTelmd/id445338527?mt=8">
     
<p>Apple<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialap.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29163891/?lang=en&countrycode=BD ">
<p>Blackberry<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialbb.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/itelmobiledialer/de0e1e5b-aaad-40b5-bc34-ea60159b7851 ">
<p>Windows<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialw.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">
<p>Nokia<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialn.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>PC
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialp.png">
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>Aero Voice
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialav.png">
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>
    <img class="top" src="images/dialksa.png">
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">

<p>Android<br>Dialer</p>
<img class="top" src="images/dialaplus.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iteliTelmd/id445338527?mt=8">
     
<p>Apple<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialap.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29163891/?lang=en&countrycode=BD ">
<p>Blackberry<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialbb.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/itelmobiledialer/de0e1e5b-aaad-40b5-bc34-ea60159b7851 ">
<p>Windows<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialw.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
<a a target="_blank" href="http://download.aero-voice.com">
<p>Nokia<br>Dialer</p>
<img src="images/dialn.png">
<p class="button">Download</p>
<p class="button">OP CODE<br>22960</p>
</a>

    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>PC
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialp.png">
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dialer1">
        <p>Aero Voice
            <br>Dialer</p>
        <img src="images/dialav.png">
        <p class="button">Download</p>
        <p class="button">OP CODE
            <br>22960</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't give my desired result. the image change is happening but div is same size and not lowering the elements below

Comment: @Saud check now - it does shift more elegantly :)

Comment: this seems to work. except im constrained to the gap between the two rows of buttons . is there a way where the elements below would shift rather than the div being constrained to the gap between the two rows. i hope thats clear :)